# T_SQL. Подскажите, как получить дату из следующих переменных типа int: день, месяц, год

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
declare @day int = 15;
declare @month int = 11;
declare @year int = 1990;

declare @date date = ???
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этого есть встроенная функция: `DATEFROMPARTS()`

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @day INT = 15
    , @month INT = 11
    , @year INT = 1990;

DECLARE @date DATE = DATEFROMPARTS(@year, @month, @day);

-- test
SELECT @date AS Result;
```

**Результат**

```
+------------+
|   Result   |
+------------+
| 1990-11-15 |
+------------+
```